# get id of checkbox created from loop php

Tags: php, checkbox

How would i get the value of the checkboxes that have been selected from these checkboxes created with a loop in php:

```
<?php
while($rowequipment = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlequipment)) {
   echo '<input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" value="'.$rowequipment['equipmentid'].'"/>
         <input type="text" name="count[]" id="count[]" size="3" value=""/>' .
         $rowequipment['description']."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: That will produce illegal HTML: it is not allowed to have more than one element with any particular id value.

Comment: If you create the id programatically, then you already have the ID. Can you specify your question further?

Comment: The question doesnt make sense. Can you give us more info so we can help you

Comment: Nothing wrong with the above code! The name attribute of HTML forms elements are CDATA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above commenters are wrong: The **name attributes for HTML form elements are of type CDATA**. Thus, your code is correct. [HTML definition found here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4).

The `id` attributes are useless, unless you need to operate using JavaScript over the DOM tree. In case you just want to process the control's values using PHP, just drop the `id`s.

In case you POSTed data, this iterates over all elements named equipment[]:

```
foreach( $_POST[ 'equipment' ] as checkBoxIndex => checkBoxValue ) {

   echo '<br />Checkbox ' . checkBoxIndex . ' has value [' . checkBoxValue . ']';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming you're generating these checkboxes in your PHP code and want to match those with checked = "checked" attribute later (maybe in other file).
As others mentioned, the HTML made by the code is not valid, fix it and then you can get what you want using DOM and XPath:

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($yourMarkup);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($html);
$checkboxes = $xpath->query("*/input[@type='checkbox' and @checked='checked']");
```

`if (!is_null($checkboxes)) {
    foreach ($checkboxes as $checkbox) {
        echo $checkbox->nodeValue;
    }
}`

If you want to get the checkboxes values on form post, then use `$_POST['key']` which key is checkbox `name` attribute.